# Error with model and decoding Json from Rapid API using Swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, api, urlsession

I have been trying to create a URLRequest using RapidAPI. Unfornautaly, I am struggling with making my model by printing my json. The error I am receiving is ""Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a number instead.", underlyingError: nil)". Having a hard time creating a model using the API documentation.

```
  func apiCall(){
    guard let url = URL(string:"https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/seasons") else 
     {return}
    
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    let headers = [
        "X-RapidAPI-Key": "",
        "X-RapidAPI-Host": "api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com"
    ]
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        
        if let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 
        response.statusCode == 200 {
            do{
                let info = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data)
                print(info.response?.first?.number ?? 0)
            }catch let error{
                print(error)
            }
        
        
        }
    
    }.resume()
}

struct Model: Decodable{

let results: Int?
let response: [Response]?
}

struct Response: Decodable{
let number: Int?
}



 {
5 items
    "get":"seasons/"
    "parameters":[]0 items
    "errors":[0 items
    ]
    "results":7
    "response":[7 items
    0:2015
    1:2016
    2:2017
    3:2018
    4:2019
    5:2020
    6:2021
    ]
    }
```

Comment: There is no `number` in `Response`. It seems like it's a Dictionary with where keys are numerical values, there is no `number` key.

Comment: @Larme would you happen to know how to decode a dictionary like so?

Comment: I'd tend to say: `let response: [String: Int]`? But it's unclear if values are `Int` or `String`, since what you give isn't valid JSON. For instance Keys in JSON Dictionary needs to be `String`, to it should be `["0": 2015, "1": 2016...]`, or if values are String: ``["0": "2015", "1": "2016"...]`.

Comment: @Larme Yeah I noticed that problem too, thanks

Comment: `print("Response stringified: \(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)")` to be sure what's your JSON. Is it an array of numbers? A dictionary? Also, you might want to hide your private keys.

Comment: @Larme The actual JSON is `{"get":"seasons\/","parameters":[],"errors":[],"results":7,"response":[2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]}`

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding (single) struct of the JSON is

```
struct Model: Decodable{
    let get: String
    let results: Int
    let response : [Int]
}
```

The actual types of `parameters` and `errors` is unclear, I omitted the struct members.

And to print the first number in the `response` **array** write

```
print(info.response.first ?? 0)
```